# Eclipse e4 part toolbars in window left aligned

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

Is there a simple way to have a left-aligned toolbar inside of a part?

Normally when I add tool items to the toolbar of a part, they are rendered on the right side of the part stack the part is in. This area is swapped out once another part is selected.

I would like my toolbars to be inside of the part, preferably at the top.

No by accident I selected an icon that was 32x32 for a command I put into my toolbar. And this is what happened:

[image: Toolbars]

The toolbar moved inside of the part - great - but it was right aligned.

Is there any way to move the toolbar to the left? I have no problems using bigger icons for my action, my UI designers would be happy too :)

Comment: I don't think you can do that using the part toolbar in the Application.e4xmi. You can always just create an ordinary `ToolBar` control in your code for the contents of the part.

Comment: I would like to use the xmi to configure the toolbars. If I use the `Toolbar` I would have to configure and call the commands manually in code ... or is there a simpler way to like the `ToolItem`s to handlers and commands?

Comment: Using the ECommandService and EHandlerService it is just a few lines of code to execute a command. At the lowest level  the part toolbar is handled by a `CTabFolder` - it is possible to override the tab folder renderer which would allow you to put the tool bar on the left, **but** tab folder renderers are hard to write.